# Argument doesn't recognized if passed with QProcess

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qprocess, mplayer

I have difficult to pass the `-vo` argument to mplayer using `QProcess`,
Here a minimal example:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QString program;
    program = "C:\\mplayer-svn-38008\\mplayer.exe";

    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "-vo gl" << "C:\\test.mp4"; 

    QProcess *m_process = new QProcess(this);
    m_process->start(program, arguments);
}
```

The process outputs:

> Unknown option on the command line: -vo gl

using the same argument on Windows shell leads to the correct behavior:

```
>mplayer -vo gl C:/test.mp4
```

Also, removing that argument from the `QStringList` works.
Why the `-vo` option is recognized from command line but not from `QProcess`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to separate each argument that is separated by a space:

```
arguments << "-vo"<< "gl" << "C:\\test.mp4";
```

Comment: Ahh, that's finally resolving to a simply typo. How silly not to check using the debugger what's passed to the `arguments`.

Comment: Well, I've checked with the debugger and the output string seemed correct: "-vo gl", "C:\\test.mp4"

Comment: How should I catch the "typo"?

Comment: @Mark No, typo is that you were wrong to write it but that is something that Qt do not document.